# Integrate Fabric Android app With iOS App in Digit

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric, fabric-digits

When Integrating two apps it's essential to add Digit Key and secret key. In swift there is a function to do this like :-

```
 // Swift
 Digits.sharedInstance().startWithConsumerKey("your_key", consumerSecret: "your_secret")
```

So I searched in the documentation to find the equivalent code for the android. But didn't find the code yet. So how can I ad iOS app Digits secret key and consumer key in my android app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this from the Fabric team.Problem is that they didn't clearly mention that we can use digit key and secret in TwitterAuthConfig. and they told me :-

> you should use your Twitter or Digits consumer key and secret in **TwitterAuthConfig("consumerKey", "consumerSecret")**
>   I'll let the team know that this was confusing.

So you can simply add your Digit consumer key and consumer secret in here :-

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =  new TwitterAuthConfig("consumerKey", "consumerSecret");
Fabric.with(this, new TwitterCore(authConfig), new Digits());
```